# Per Company Sign-in Providers / Options with Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I’m currently working on a POC to use Azure AD B2C in a multi-tenant architecture where we have a single database of users tied to companies.  Presently we have around 1000 different companies. The question I couldn’t determine from documentation and Azure support is whether I can do the following:

1. Allow company admins to choose the sign in providers they want for their users.
2. Provide per company branding to the user flows.

Of course, my main consideration is doing this in a configurable and scalable way.  Right now we only have a single B2C tenant setup and unclear if we need one per company vs managing it all together well.

Finally, is this even the right product for these outcomes?

Comment: Assess your requirements > Use B2C custom policies > Consider using the B2C Extensions library > Evaluate the scalability of your solution.